# Appending CSPRNG generated salt to a string that needs to be hashed

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, cryptography

Reading about [generating salt using Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator (CSPRNG)](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#properhashing). This salt then will be appended to a string that needs to be hashed.

However, the salt generated by CSPRNG function (for PHP I'm using [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)) is actually binary data.

Confused about how I should append this binary data to a string, I saw this [PHP example for creating hash](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode). It encodes binary data.

So I just wanted to know if that is what I need to do. I need to encode salt to get a string. Then I can append that salt to a string that needs to be hashed. Or are there other ways of adding salt to a string?

**note** I'm not hashing a password

Comment: Are you hashing a password? In that case you should use a specialized password hash function that takes care of all this. For example for bcrypt based hashing there is a standard technique which uses a [variant of Base64](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39465/is-this-code-snippet-good-enough-for-password-hash-and-salt/39476#39476).

Comment: Then using a salt is unusual. When encrypting we generally use IVs instead. Without enough context, we can't really hep you.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the salt to a string? Hash functions take bytes as input.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to hash a password, please use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`, and probably add `password_needs_rehash()` - see https://www.php.net/password_hash.

You might notice that these functions are available since PHP 5.5.0 - if you are using an earlier version of PHP, you can add [this compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to make it work with PHP starting at 5.3.7.

It can't get very much easier than that.

Comment: But you should have a look at the github repository to see how the return value of openssl_random_pseudo_bytes is used as the salt for a hash.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to first convert your string into binary data using an encoding. UTF-8 encoding is probably best for most use cases. Don't forget to (at least) document which character encoding is used.

Now concatenate the salt and the encoded string. Again, you need to (at least) document the size of the salt. Please make sure you use concatenation of bytes, not strings. Bytes can have any value, including invalid characters, control characters etc.

After the concatenation you can feed the resulting byte array into the hashing function.

---

If you have trouble with byte concatenation in PHP, you could use hexadecimal values instead. But don't forget to convert them back into bytes before feeding them into the hash method.